# Nginx: Can I setup a limit_req_zone with a key with IP + URI?

Tags: nginx, http, rate-limiting

I'm trying to setup Nginx [limit_req module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) to limit the request rate that any IP can make to the same URL.

I would like to define the `limit_req_zone` with a key that is composed by a combination of the client's IP and the request URI. That is, instead of this:

`limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=req_dev:10m rate=2r/s;`

Something like this:

```
set $ip_url "$binary_remote_addr$request_uri"
limit_req_zone $ip_url zone=req_dev:10m rate=2r/s;
```

But that does not work because `set` cannot be called in the `http` context:

```
nginx: [emerg] "set" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:47
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Just to be clear: I don't want to limit the rate on a specific URL. I want to avoid an IP from hitting the same URL more than twice a second.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the key to whatever you want in `limit_req_zone`.

```
limit_req_zone "$binary_remote_addr$request_uri" zone=req_dev:10m rate=2r/s;
```

Note that this requires at least nginx 1.7.6.